# Assets not uploading files in Chrome, works fine in Firefox

Tags: add-on, assets

When I try to upload a file in Chrome the "Uploads files"-button is dimmed. When I click it I can select files with the browser file browser, but when Assets tries to upload it stops after a few seconds and nothing appears. I do however get an error in the console: Uncaught Error: QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR: DOM Exception 22.

Works fine in Firefox. Tried both 2.0.1 and 2.0.2. Developing in a local environment, with no .htaccess file.

Answer (score 1):

If the button is dimmed, that should mean that you don’t have a folder selected on the left, so Assets isn’t sure where to upload the file.

Comment: Still experiencing this problem. Now on 2.0.5. There are no folders to click on, and no errors in the console. I've also made sure that there is no cross-domain issues.

If I go to the Assets module page no folders appear. However if I go to "Update Indexes" I can see all folders, but when I select one and press the "Update Indexes" button nothing happens — except the button greys out.